# Creating shader files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, shader, file-extension, directx-11

I'm trying to learn some DirectX11 and I found good tutorial I'm following; however, for some reason the program crashes (The window appears but then a "not responding" message box appears), even though the build was successful. There were some thing about creating shader-files the author did specify on how to do, and i wanted to make sure I'm not making any errors there and that why my program crashes. So my questions are :

1. How do you create a shader files? In the tutorial we are using the extension .fx, but when you add a file in vs you can only choose from .h and .cpp . Do you only have to select .cpp and then add .fx in the end of the file name?
2. In what directory is the file suppose to be? (My files are currently in Source Files)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes that will work. Another way to do it is just to create a .txt then change the extention to .fx
   (To show the file extention just open any folder, click on the organize button in the menu then choose "folder and search options". Uncheck the box "Hide extentions for know file types" under the tab view). After you change the extention you can open the document in notepad and write your code there
2. Go in to your project folder (in windows file system) and create a map called Data. Add you .fx file there. Then go to your solution explorer and rigth click on the project and choose properties. Go to Build Events -> Pre- Build Events. Add the line "xcopy /y /d "$(ProjectDir)Data" "$(OutDir)" in the box "Command Line". Now when building your project the files will be copied to the rigth place and you will be able to use your .fx file.

Answer (score 0):

The .fx is associate it with an effect file. Meaning you have a combination of many shaders in the same file. Can you post some code of your render loop... also, are you calling the Present method?i.e.,

```
m_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
```